# Child Frame calling a parent frame. Code Design

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, jdialog

I have a Code design question. Let me explain the scenario and then the question. I have 2 Panels below
[image]

Basically, the first panel on clicking start, opens the second panel. On the Second panel when the file is chosen (background blue). That file needs to be opened in the editor pane of the first panel.

The question is: What is the good practice to do it. Both my panels are separate classes. Currently the second panel keeps a reference to the first panel. And on selection, calls the respective method of the first class to output the csv. This is a bad design anyday.
How should the children frames refresh an aspect of the parent frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `JDialog(parent, modal)` instead of `JFrame`, could be depends of modality
- create `JDialog` only one time, reuse this container for another event came from parent
- `JDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`, then every next actions are only about `setVisible(true/false)` wrapped in `invokeLater()`
- then return (check if contents changed, changes back to the parent
- you can to put there verifications by users action from `JOptionPane("DYW to save changes ??"))`

Comment: you can to describe that you'll able to fills data from one class to the another (good desing), then you have to check if is there some changes, and/or all data are valid for parent window, you can triggering (after validations / or validations isn't passed) next user action by verifying in user side, this action could be passed, verifications retuns some exceptions from rulles, or uses can roll_back whole action (nothing happened, nothing added, e.i.)

Comment: But how will the JDIalog return the fileName?

Comment: please whats is fileName, there no issue (in Java) pass or returns any Object, betweens two Object, Classses, voids e.g.

Comment: Small misunderstanding. When the second dialog is made visible. The user selects a fileName. This fileName needs to be returned to the first panel. This is what I am not understanding the the good design.

Comment: desing could be select whatever, then refresh child (prepared) JDialog with data came from parent, show child myDialog.setVisible(true), wrapped in invokeLater, if action ended then to hide JDialog with myDialog.setVisible(false), I wouldnot be going ..., don't to create interactive windows untill you'll be able to manage whole life_cycle, sure up to you